# Jquery: using this inside class internal functions, working as handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Suppose, we have the following code:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Say hello">
```

Javascript:

```
function test ()
{
    this.message = "hello";
    this.on_change = function (){
        alert(this.message);
    }

    this.on_change();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var my_object = new test();
    $('#button').click(my_object.on_change);
});
```

my_object must print "Hello" in 2 cases:

1. When the instance is created (works)
2. When clicking the button "Say hello" (doesn't work)

In the second case it prints "Undefined", because `this` refers to "button" object, and not to the instance of `test` class.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s81v1s8h/)

Comment: Create a context of `this`: http://jsfiddle.net/s81v1s8h/1/

Comment: 1). `$('#button').click($.proxy(my_object.on_change, my_object));` 2). `$('#button').click(my_object.on_change.bind(my_object));`
3). `$('#button').click(function() { my_object.on_change(); });`

Answer (score 0):

Try to remember context of `this` to some variable:

```
var self = this;
this.message = "hello";
...
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s81v1s8h/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like one of those cases where you should actually create a function for your handler. :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var my_object = new test();
    $('#button').click(function(){
        my_object.on_change();
    });
});
```